# Android - ExpandableListView content cut off at bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, android-constraintlayout

I'm new to Android so I'm probably just doing something dumb but this is what my table looks like: [image]

I thought it was just that the bottom nav bar was covering the content, but when I tested it on a device where the bottom nav bar is on the device and not the screen I had the same problem. Here's my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TipActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tip_list_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">
    </ExpandableListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a bottom constraint on the listview?

Comment: @tyczj When I add ' layout_constriantBottom_toBottomOf="parent" ' the issue persists and content then appears underneath the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. By putting the Toolbar and the ExpandableListView inside a vertical linear layout and leaving everything else the same, the views fit correctly.